# Extracting layers in Keras model

Tags: neural-network, keras

The following is the `model.summary()` output of a keras model. I am trying to extract a sub-model from this, that starts from the output of layer `flatten_1` and ends at the output of the last layer (`dense_3`). Is it possible? If yes, What would be the Keras syntax?

```python
zero_padding2d_1 (ZeroPaddin (None, 226, 226, 3)       0    
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
zero_padding2d_2 (ZeroPaddin (None, 114, 114, 64)      0         
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
zero_padding2d_3 (ZeroPaddin (None, 58, 58, 128)       0         
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 200704)            0         
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                12845120  
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 256)               16640     
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 514
```